# App blocked calling O365 Discovery Service

Tags: service, office365, service-discovery

The app was registered and worked fine to call O365 Discovery Service to discover API endpoints. But it stopped working lately. I know Discovery Service is to be obsoleted next year, but it should still work now.

Error is:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "101, Microsoft.Online.Services.O365Discovery.O365DiscoveryException",
    "message": "The app ID is blocked for access of the O365 Discovery Service."
  }
}
```

Comment: I see this too, for a new app though. Did you find any info about this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Newly created apps does not have access to O365 discovery endpoint due to deprecation. You can now use the graph api to get the info you want.

More info can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/how-to/discover-service-endpoints